# Using same Jenkinsfile for two separate jobs in same repo

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have two separate Jenkins jobs that will run on one repository: My Jenkinsfile has a step that will run with this property enabled: `enableZeroDownTime`. The purpose of the 2nd Jenkins Job is to run the step with this property `enableZeroDownTime` disabled. Does anyone know how I can control it using the same Jenkinsfile? Can I pass that using some parameter based on any properties file? I am really confused on this.

```
stage('CreateCustomer') {
            steps {
                script {
                   common.runStage("@CreateCustomer")
                   common.runStage("@SetOnboardingCustomerManifest")
                   common.runStage("@enableZeroDownTime")
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I believe I answered your question.  You essentially need to remove the parameters{} block from your declarative pipeline and then add the parameters through the web interface.  I also put in an example of how to configure two pipelines to use different parameters ( not just different values ). If this answers your question please accept the answer and upvote

Comment: If the goal is to avoid code duplication when using two pipelines perhaps [Shared Libraries](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

I currently run multiple pipelines that use the same Jenkinsfile.  The change to conditionally execute a stage is trivial.

```
stage('CreateCustomer') {
   when {
      environment name: 'enableZeroDownTime', value: 'true'
   }

   steps {
      script {
         common.runStage("@CreateCustomer")
         common.runStage("@SetOnboardingCustomerManifest")
         common.runStage("@enableZeroDownTime")
       }
   }
}
```

The *CreateCustomer* stage will only run when the *enableZeroDownTime* parameter is set to true ( it can be a String parameter with value true, or a boolean parameter ).

The trick here is that you **cannot** add the `parameters{}` block to your declarative pipeline.  For example if you had the following

```
parameters {
    string(name: 'enableZeroDownTime', defaultValue: 'true') 
}
```

Both pipelines would default to true.  If you had the following

```
parameters {
    string(name: 'enableZeroDownTime', defaultValue: '') 
}
```

Both pipelines would default to a blank default value.

**Even if you manually save a different default value to the pipeline after creation it will be overwritten next run with a blank default value.**

Instead you simply need to remove the `parameters{}` block altogether and manually add the parameters through the web interface

[image: Parameterizing Jenkins pipeline through web interace]

## Additionally...

Additionally it is possible to have two pipelines use the same Jenkinsfile with different parameters.  For example, lets say Pipeline A had a *enableZeroDownTime* parameter defaulted to true and Pipeline B had no parameters at all.  In this case you can add an environment variable of the same name and set the value equal to the following ternary expression

```
environment {
    enableZeroDownTime = "${params.enableZeroDownTime != null ? "${params.enableZeroDownTime}" : false}"
}
```

You can then reference this parameter in the when declarative ( or anywhere in the pipeline ) without fear of the pipeline throwing a null pointer exception.